# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') while signing a transaction

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js

I'm getting this error

```
const key = signer.publicKey.toString();
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at Transaction.partialSign (/home/Abhi/xode/sol/testServer/testServer2/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:3045:36)
    at NodeWallet.signTransaction (/home/Abhi/xode/sol/testServer/testServer2/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet.js:23:12)
    at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/home/Abhi/xode/sol/testServer/testServer2/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/provider.js:83:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (/home/Abhi/xode/sol/testServer/testServer2/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/rpc.js:15:24)
    at async file:///home/Abhi/xode/sol/testServer/testServer2/app.js:100:20
```

I'm trying to use this function

```
const freeze = await program.methods.freezeToken().accounts({
      sender : sender,
      senderAta : senderAta,
      mint : mint,
      vaultAccount : vaultAccount,
      freezingConfig : freezingConfig,
      tokenProgram : tokenProgram,
      systemProgram : systemProgram,
      rent : rent
    }
  ).signers(walletWrapper.payer).rpc()
```

For the program account

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct FreezeToken<'info> {
    ///CHECK : Not dangerous
   #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub sender: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub sender_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

   pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = 
        [   
            b"vault".as_ref(),
            mint.key().as_ref()
        ],
        bump,
        payer = sender,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = sender,
    )]
    pub vault_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,   
      ///CHECK : Not dangerous

    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = 
        [   
            b"config".as_ref(),
            mint.key().as_ref()
        ],
        bump,
        payer = sender,
        space = 90
    )]
    pub freezing_config : Account<'info,FreezingConfig>,
    
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    pub token_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

I feel i'm missing some parameters or arguments, but i can't figure it out.

The parameters i use are

```
const sender = new PublicKey("U4NHM8DNT3kCNrRtB9ymgt1mcR6RBaHwUHWLoxM4KTF");
  const senderAta = new PublicKey("2zfkpS8VNWk2t8B2737B6xxFVw8WFNjF3qWXvtQAbgK4");
  const mint = new PublicKey("9jcbX9YT6ZzvEsuUrfxcV8Chv3uz7TMmPo4MXXDc5UhV");
  const vaultAccount = new PublicKey("9UgS3GBfQVmsEMVje5tniYgYszDs5G7orcw8r71Mdesb");

  const freezingConfig = new PublicKey('FK81EDxxU7pPwm5BSs5oFQt5deoRxynuJwu8bnr4nbhf')
  const tokenProgram = new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA");
  const systemProgram = new PublicKey('11111111111111111111111111111111');
  const rent = new PublicKey("SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111");
const walletWrapper =new anchor.Wallet(walletKeyPair);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your account parameters should be the Public Key of the account, not the Keypair. For instance if you generate a new account using `let newAccount = anchor.web3.generate()` to pass into your instruction call, pass it in as `newAccount: newAccount.PublicKey()`.

Comment: which parameter should i replace it with?

Comment: All the accounts are public key type and correct as well, i double checked them

Comment: In that case the issue is likely with your signer. That should be a `Keypair` instead of a `PublicKey`

Comment: tried passing passing keypair,wallet and pulickey but the same error

Comment: Update the question to include a more complete code sample where you show the definition of all the parameters you use in the function call

Comment: Updated the accounts

Comment: walletWrapper? Update its definition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138217/discussion-between-abhishek-faliya-and-ademola).